# WebConfigurationManager when using custom routes in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

When I'm using custom routes,  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings doesn't seem to return the correct data for the real virtual directory.

What I mean is, if I go to here, where MyApp/MyDir matches the physical directory structure of my View:

```
 http://localhost/MyApp/MyDir/Index
```

WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings correctly returns appSettings from the web.config in MyApp/MyDir.

I also have a custom route which goes to the same controller action:

```
 http://localhost/MyApp/Home
```

WebConfigurationManager doesn't seem to recognize my appSettings in this case (and just returns the web application root web.config's appSettings).

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe there is an AllowOverride="true" attribute you can place in your root's web.config in order to allow the child web.configs to override values.  I have never personally used it so I didnt want to answer, but perhaps that will help.   Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to have any effect.